# How to get the _id of posts that are instantiated in posts_list?

Tags: javascript, meteor, telescope

I need to get the `_id` of all `post_item` being displayed in Telescope. It is not the posts_itens that are in the Collection but those being displayed.

*Using Google Translate*.

Comment: There's no easy way to do this right now I'm afraid. Maybe there should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cursor.map()`, if you are trying to get an array with `_id` values of `post_item` elements:

```
var postIdsArr = Posts.find({}, {
    _id: 1
}).map(function(post) {
    return post._id;
});
```

Read more about the [cursor.map() method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map).

Comment: I know that you are working with [Telescope](http://www.telescopeapp.org). Could you please edit your question and explain your desired result?